# CollectionAssert.AreEqual Failing

Tags: c#, .net, nunit

I am trying to compare two Lists using

```
 CollectionAssert.AreEqual(ListExpected, ListActual);
```

But I am getting an exception

```
Expected and actual are both <System.Collections.Generic.List`1[API.Program.Relation]> with 11 elements
  Values differ at index [0]
  Expected: <API.Program.Relation>
  But was:  <API.Program.Relation>
```

But when I compared the zero element using `Assert.AreEqual` on field by field everything was fine.

Any idea why I cannot compare using  `CollectionAssert`

Comment: Are they actually reference equal? Even if all the data is the same, it might not be the same instance.

Comment: are the items in the collections you are comparing implementing `Equals` and `GetHashCode` properly?

Comment: Were the references of item zero the same, or just the field values?

Comment: @ken  they are only field values equals , they are pointing to a different objects

Comment: @NightWalker -- I think that's your problem.

Comment: @ken from msdn: Two collections are equal if they have the same elements in the same order and quantity. Elements are equal if their values are equal, not if they refer to the same object. The values of elements are compared using Equals by default.

Comment: That's poor wording, I feel, on the part of the MSDN.  It says it uses `Equals()` which if you don't implement will just be reference equality.

Comment: You might want to overload API.Program.Relation.ToString() to get a visual rendition of what's different.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs True, or examine under debugger.  I'd be surprised if CollectionAssert did a reflective compare, but then again, it is just an Assert, so performance isn't critical.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An object is "declared" equal to another object in .NET is if its `Equals(object other)` method returns true. You need to implement that method for your `API.Program.Relation` class, otherwise .NET considers your objects different unless they are reference-equal. The fact that all fields are the same does not matter to .NET: if you need field-by-field equality semantics, you need to provide an implementation of `Equals` that supports it.

When you override `Equals`, don't forget to override `GetHashCode` as well - these must be overriden together.

If you do not want to or cannot override `Equals` for some reason, you could use [an overload of `CollectionAssert.AreEqual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243703%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) that takes an instance of `IComparer` to assist in comparing collection elements.

Comment: And when you override Equals/GetHashCode, consider making the class immutable too.

Comment: @HenkHolterman or at least those fields that are used to calculate equality and hash code